# GEdit Snippets don't seem to work on remote files?

Tags: nautilus, gedit

I am attempting to use gedit's "snippets" plugin. They work great in Ubuntu, but I've since switched to Debian. Now, even though I have enabled Snippets, they don't work when I am editing files on a remote (SFTP) server.

They work great locally (create file, set language as PHP, try snippets), which is of small comfort, since I'd prefer to work on the remote server.

Is this a bug in gedit Debian? I am using Squeeze.

Reproduction steps (Using Debian Squeeze 6.0.2):

- In gedit, enable Snippets (Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Check "Snippets")
- Open a new SFTP connection in nautilus (Places -> Home -> Ctrl-L -> sftp://any.site.that/you/can/access/through/SFTP
- Double-click on a php file to open it in gEdit
- Type "foreach" and press tab. The rest of the code should be automatically filled in. Note that this does not occur.
- Open a new document (Ctrl-N)
- Set the language (at the bottom) from "Plain Text" to "PHP"
- Type "foreach" and press tab. Note that the rest of the code **does** automatically populate now.

Comment: Could you please provide a clearly defined test case so others can try to reproduce (and hopefully fix) your problem.

Comment: Hi N.N. thanks for the comment. I'll try to elaborate in the original post.

Comment: This may not be due to snippets not working in remote mode but due to gedit not updating correctly to what type of text its viewing since it works when you change from plain text to php.

Comment: Hi N.N., attempted to switch the text type from PHP to Plain Text, then back, but to no avail. I initially mentioned Ubuntu as Ubuntu tends to use more updated packages...

Comment: Do snippets work on this Debian server when working locally and not thru SFTP ? (please include @harrymc in your answer).

Comment: @harrymc, yes, they work fine if I am not editing a file through the sftp protocol. (i.e. If I open a file on the hard drive, or start a new file)

Comment: Could it be a problem that when using SFTP you do not use the same user account as for the local logon ?

Comment: Hello again @harrymc. Good question, I hadn't thought of that, but the username is identical for both the local and remote accounts. I also have the public rsa key copied over to the remote hosts' `authorized_keys` file, so I can log in without a password.

Comment: What happens if you use [gedit-ftp-browser](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-ftp-browser/) instead of nautilus ? Or use gedit under sudo ?

Comment: Hm. gedit-ftp-browser doesn't seem to handle SFTP connections, and I cannot run nautilus under root, and by extension, cannot edit any files under the root user in gedit.

Comment: One more : What happens if you open gedit with the file as parameter from the command-line in the context of some local directory, instead of launching it by double-click inside the SFTP context ?

Comment: Snippets work as intended, although as far as I know, there is no way to open a file hosted remotely from the local command line. I've filed a bug against gedit in GNOME's bugzilla now: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662103

Comment: My last question was because I suspected a bug in gedit when invoked with a remote current directory. My final step would have been to recommend filing a bug report, but you were faster.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Feel free to submit a non-answer, I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: Done, and wishing you a speedy return on your bug report ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the comments, gedit seems to work correctly as regarding snippets when invoked in a "normal" context.

It only seems to have a problem when invoked by double-clicking on a remote file, so that it executes with a remote directory as the current.
This indicates a rather puzzling bug in gedit.

The poster has accordingly filed a [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662103). The last entry dating from 2011-10-18 says :

> Quite a lot of fixes came into snippets in the version 3.2.0 
> would be
>   good to get this tested in that version.

Comment: harrymc, thanks again for your help. The bug seems to have been recently fixed upstream. Hooray!